# brew install libusb linking failed

Tags: homebrew, libusb

I am installing *libusb* with *brew* in my Mac

> brew install libusb

The linking step failed as below

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local 

Could not symlink lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib 

Target /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib already exists. 

You may want to remove it:   rm '/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:   brew link
--overwrite libusb
```

So I removed the existing libusb with

> sudo rm '/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib'

and then did a link

> brew link --overwrite libusb

The linking doesn't work, shows error below

> Error: Could not symlink lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib
>
> /usr/local/lib is not writable.

If I try

> sudo brew link --overwrite libusb

instead, that doesn't work either. What am I missing?

I am using OSX El Capitan version 10.11.4 (15E65)

Comment: Try smacking it harder... `brew rm libusb --force`, `brew install libusb`

Comment: Also, if you are planning on using it to scan, be aware that `Image Capture` squats on the scanner and needs to be killed before you can scan. Oh, I may mention *smacking* and *killing*, but I'm not really a violent person  ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell after messing up brew and recovering, I did `brew rm libusb --force`, `sudo brew install libusb` (wo sudo was permission denied). Seemed to work wo error. Now if I do `which libusb`, it doesn't show anything. Does that mean libusb is still not linked?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. None of the suggestions helped-- the root of the problem seems to be that brew installs libusb as "libusb-1.0" (with the -1.0 appended to the file names and package names). I don't have a solution yet, but manually creating a non-1.0 version of the .pc file at least let pkg-config see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If things seem not to work with `homebrew`, my general strategy is first to try:

```
brew doctor
```

and do whatever the good doctor recommends.

If that fails, I tend to uninstall things, normally using `--force` which really does a good clean-up and removes old versions. So, in your case:

```
brew rm libusb --force
```

Then re-install the *"unhappy"* package. So, in your case:

```
brew install libusb
```

In answer to your new question in the comments. Your installation looks correct because `libusb` isn't an executable program - it is just a library without any associated command-line tools - so it won't show up when you run `which libusb`.

You can see the constituent parts of the package with this command:

```
brew ls libusb

/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/lib/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/lib/ (2 other files)
```

And, as you can see, there is no stand-alone executable program in `/usr/local/bin` called `libusb`, there are just

- libusb.h - a C header file you would compile against
- libusb...dylib - a dynamic library you would link against
- libusb...pc - which supplies the info for the `pkgconfig` tool

So, if you wanted to compile and link an application against `libusb`, you would run `pkg-config` like this to find out the *"Include path"* and linker details

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libusb

-I/usr/local/Cellar/libusb-compat/0.1.5/include      \ 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.20/include/libusb-1.0 \
-L/usr/local/Cellar/libusb
```

which means your compilation command would look like this:

```
gcc yourApp.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libusb) -o yourApp
```

Comment: Looks like I have problem having pkg-config the libusb path. I think this is beyond the scope of this question so posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578535/package-libusb-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path)